# Set Form authentication in WEB API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, form-authentication

Actually i have two project. One for Mvc and another one is Web Api. I have written form as below in mvc project.

```
 <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input class="customCheckBox" onclick="setIsRemember()" type="checkbox" name="" value="false"><label for=""><span><span></span></span>Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <button id="buttonSubmit" class="btn btn-default">LOG IN</button>
</form>
```

Then i have written script for cross domain as below,

```
 $("#buttonSubmit").click(function (e) {
            var user =
                {
                    UserName:  $("#email").val(),
                    Password: $("#pwd").val(),
                    IsRemember: $(".customCheckBox").val() 
                }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:55016/api/ajaxapi/loginmethod",
                data: user,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.Success == false) {
                        alert("login fail");
                    }
                    if (response.Success == true) {
                      alert("login true");
                    }
                }
            });
 });
```

I have written login credential checking in web Api. After login success i have set form authentication as below in web api source,

```
public class UserLogOn
    {
        public interface IFormsAuthentication
        {
            void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie);

            void SignOut();
        }

        public IFormsAuthentication FormsAuth
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
public void FormsChange(IFormsAuthentication formsAuth)
        {
            this.FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationService();
        }

        public void LogOnUserCookieCreation(UserValuesForLogOn user)
        {
            this.FormsChange(null);
            this.FormsAuth.SignIn(user.UserName, user.IsRemember);
            if (user.IsRemember)
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("SignedIn");
                cookie.Values.Add("UserName", user.UserName);
                cookie.Values.Add("Password", user.Password);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true);
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
        }
 public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthentication
        {
            public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
            }

            public void SignOut()
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            }
        }
```

When this above code is working if set authentication in same project. But its not working when set authentication using webapi. Please share your suggestion. 
Thanks......

Comment: `its not working` - let's take a while to digest the vast amount of information you have provided here ... while I'm doing that, any errors in the browser **developer** tools console to add to this wealth of information?

Comment: Do it separated projects and different hosts? If yes, you have to change your project structure to use only one host for both projects (The API project is just a shared library instead of a completely different project).

Comment: `cross domain` - should we assume your server issues CORS headers?

Comment: No errors displayed so only i have shared code information.@JaromandaX

Comment: Is it possible? =>form written in one project and authentication set in another project..@JaromandaX